# Static model class is null in feature test laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have this test in my feature folder and I've imported model on top of the class but it keeps failing and I think $event is null!

```
namespace Tests\Feature\Events;

use App\Models\Event;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class EventManagementTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * @test
     * @group event
     * A basic feature test to check event registration
     *
     */
    public function an_event_can_be_registered()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $response = $this->post('/events',$this->data());

        $event = Event::first();

        $this->assertCount(1,Event::all());
        $response->assertRedirect('/events/' . $event->event_id);
    }

    private function data()
    {
        return[
            'event_title'       => 'Internet Businesses',
            'event_location'    => 'Milad Tower',
            'event_description' => 'In this event Amin will present you the most recent methods in Internet Businesses',
            'event_start_date'  => '2020-06-01',
            'event_end_date'    => '2020-06-05',
        ];
    }
...
}
```

And this is the results:

FAIL Tests\Feature\Events\EventManagementTest ✕ an event can be registered

Tests: 1 failed

Failed asserting that two strings are equal. 
....

--- Expected

+++ Actual

@@ @@

-'http://localhost/events/1'

+'http://localhost/events'

these two URIs are different and I think that's because $event is null and I don't know why?!

UPDATE: I've added the Route and the controller:

```
Route::post('/events','Web\EventsController@store');
```

and the controller is:

```
public function store(){
        $event = Event::create($this->validateRequest());
        return redirect('/events/'.$event->event_id);
 }

protected function validateRequest(){
        return request()->validate([
            'event_title'       => 'required',
            'event_location'    => 'required',
            'event_description' => 'required',
            'event_start_date'  => 'required',
            'event_end_date'    => 'required',
        ]);
 }
```

Comment: Can we see the route you are calling?

Comment: @mrhm Sure! I've updated the question

Comment: and how does your event model looks?

Comment: @mrhn Just guarded the event ID like: protected $guarded = ['event_id'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your do not use the standard primary id column, therefor you need to define it in your model. If it is not defined, it will not set it on `create()`.

```
class Event extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'event_id';
}
```